# Dynamic search bar - Adding element from drop down in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm programming in ASP.NET MVC5. On one of my views I need to be able to create a search bar. For this example, lets say you are searching for names. When you start typing a person's name, all of the results will be displayed in a drop down list as you type.

Here is the tricky part that I need help with. I want there to be a button for each entry in the drop down list to "Add" that person name to a table.

For example, I'm looking for the name "Debo" As I type "D-E-B", I see the name I want in the drop down list. I click "Add" and it removes the name "Debo" from the drop down list and adds it to my table. Once "Debo" has been added to the table, I need to be able to see Debo's age and gender that I wouldn't see in the drop down list.

I don't have any code examples because I'm not even sure where to start. I've researched this like crazy, but I cannot find anything. Any help or pointing me in the right direction, will be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wonder if it would be easier to have an "Add" button outside of the drop down list. And add the selected element to the table.

Comment: A `<select>` element is generated by the OS/Browser. You cannot add a button to its option elements (you would need a jquery plugin)

Comment: Why you want to add button you can do your logic by clicking on `Item` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using autocomplete by [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).
Please refer below code hopefully it will helps you.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$("#member_CompanyName").autocomplete({
    highlightClass: "bold-text",
    search: function () {
        $(this).addClass('working');
    },
    source: function (request, response) {
        var companyDetails = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ControllerName/JsonActionResult",
            async: false,
            data: {
                "parm": request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length === 0) {
                    companyDetails[0] = {
                        label: "No Result Found",
                        Id: ""
                    };
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        companyDetails[i] = {
                            label: data[i].Value,
                            Id: data[i].Key
                        };
                        $("#no-companyfound").css("display", "none");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        response(companyDetails);
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        /*Select Function works on when you selects element from Response List*/
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "/ControllerName/JsonActionResultonClick",
            data: {
                "id": ui.item.Id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // Do your success logic here
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // Error Logic here
            }
        });
    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

**Controller Code:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult JsonActionResult(string parm) {
        // Replace your special Character like "-,~" etc from your search string
        var result = new List < KeyValuePair < string,
            string >> ();
        foreach(var item in _obj_fulldetails.GetCompanylistSearch(parm)) {
            result.Add(new KeyValuePair < string, string > (item.Value.ToString(), item.Text));
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

You can implement "Add" 
button your logic on Item select. If you still want add button you can edit response string into JS.

See my response screenshot :

[image]